# MySQL: Left join count total under range

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I am trying to produce the following table output from the below tables in my database.

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
Table-pax     Q-Length      Avg wait time            Cust ID
=====         ========      ======================   =======
1-2           7             5 minutes                4
3-4           2             6 minutes                12
5-6           0             7 minutes                NULL
7-8           0             7 minutes                NULL
```

So I have the following query used to try to produce the desired output, which is performed on my database tables:

```
SELECT concat(s.min_pax, "-", s.max_pax) as Table-pax, d.CustCount as Q-Length, s.avg_q_time, d2.cust_id
FROM `Stat_table` as s
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT est_id, COUNT(cust_id) as CustCount, pax, q_id
    FROM `Data_table`
    WHERE STATUS = "QQQ")
    GROUP BY est_id, pax) d
on d.pax >= s.min_pax AND d.pax <= s.max_pax
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT est_id, pax, cust_id, q_id
    FROM `Data_table`
    WHERE status = "QQQ")
    GROUP BY pax
    ORDER BY time ASC) d2
on d2.q_id = d.q_id
WHERE s.est_id = 1
GROUP BY concat(s.min_pax, "-", s.max_pax)
```

Database table 1 - Stat_table

```
est_id     min_pax     max_pax     avg_q_time
======     =======     =======     ==========
1          1           2           5
1          3           4           6
1          5           6           7
1          7           8           7
2          1           4           4
```

Database table 2 - Data_table

```
est_id     cust_id     pax         status     q_id     time
======     =======     ===         ======     ====     ====
1          13          3           QQQ        22       12:32:01
1          12          3           QQQ        21       11:00:41
1          1           2           QQQ        20       12:12:33
1          11          1           QQQ        19       11:12:10
1          1           1           CXL        18       12:11:07
1          10          1           QQQ        17       12:59:45
1          7           1           QQQ        16       11:05:30
1          6           1           QQQ        15       12:18:32
1          5           1           QQQ        14       12:22:12
1          4           1           QQQ        13       10:15:02
```

However, what I am getting from the aforementioned query is

```
Table-pax     Q-Length      Avg wait time            Cust ID
=====         ========      ======================   =======
1-2           1             5 minutes                1
3-4           2             6 minutes                12
5-6           0             7 minutes                NULL
7-8           0             7 minutes                NULL
```

despite there being 7 entries with status "QQQ" for pax of 1 and 2.

I've almost closing in on the solution but I just can't get around the aggregating for each category of table-pax is not as what I would like, i.e. for all pax 1 and 2 under 'Data_table', I want those to be aggregated under the output of table-pax 1-2, and all pax 3 and 4 to be aggregated under table-pax 3-4 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, but I'm not sure about last column `cust_id`, maybe can you explain this?

```
SELECT
  concat(s.min_pax, '-', s.max_pax) AS Table_pax,
  sum(d.CustCount)                  AS CustCount,
  s.avg_q_time,
  d2.cust_id
FROM Stat_table AS s
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                COUNT(cust_id) AS CustCount,
                pax,
                q_id
              FROM Data_table
              WHERE status = 'QQQ'
              GROUP BY pax) d
    ON d.pax >= s.min_pax AND d.pax <= s.max_pax
  LEFT JOIN (
              SELECT
                est_id,
                pax,
                cust_id,
                q_id
              FROM Data_table
              WHERE status = 'QQQ'
              GROUP BY pax
              ORDER BY time ASC) d2
    ON d2.q_id = d.q_id
WHERE s.est_id = 1
GROUP BY Table_pax;
```

Comment: Thank you! The sum() did it for me.

Comment: The last column "cust_id" is simply the one with the earliest time entry in Data_table